# Unable to log in to phpmyadmin on local server

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, admin

I see many questions similar to this, but so far I haven't seen this one. It may exist, I just couldn't find it.

I'm running a web server at home, and I have for many years. I've been fully disabled since 12/30/2018, and unable to work ever again, so it keeps me busy! :)

- **Ubuntu 18.04**
- **Apache2.4.54**
- **MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.39**
- **PHP 5.6 (I *still* haven't learnt me sum 7!)**

This problem is a first for me, and it's driving me nuts!!

It was running great, and I had zero issues with it! Until (DUH DUUUUH - *ominous music plays*)...

***The Issue***...*finally!*

I bring the login page up, login with my normal uname and pass, press the login button and POOF! It just goes right back to the blank login screen. I try again and same thing!

I've tried this from a local connection as well as remotely and I have the same issue.

I can debug this stuff like anyone who has been running it for the last 20+ years, like I have! But everything looks fine and there are no error reports to let me know what's going on! And it's driving me insane! I'm having to go into the terminal and manually do everything! EVERYTHING I SAY!! That or write some PHP script to do it from forms.

Boy, these programs like phpMyAdmin really spoil us!

Anyway, Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated any of Apache, MySQL, PHP or PHPAdmin ?

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version? The current 5.2 branch requires PHP 7.2 or newer, if you still need PHP 5.x compatibility (you _shouldn't_, those PHP versions have not received security fixes for _years_ now), then you need to use the old 4.9 branch.

Comment: Hmmm…that’s something I haven’t checked yet. I just do the [apt update] and [apt upgrade], so versions might have slipped by me. My system is running PHP 5.6, but 7 and 8 are also installed, just not active. When I check the version, it keeps throwing 7.2 back at me. I check configuration and 5.6 is active. My scripts are working fine, so it would have to be running 5.6. Makes me wonder if phpmyadmin sees 7.2 since Version check sees it as well…

Comment: Also, I don’t recall the phpmyadmin version. But I’ll check it in the morning and comment it in here. Thanks guys!!

Comment: Sorry, I spaced and forgot to respond with the info! I did check though and it was phpMyAdmin 5.x. So, I removed it and tried installing 4.x, which was supposed to work with my php version, and I got nothing. I also remembered that v5.x worked fine for a long time before this issue. It’s weird tho. Like it’s not even registering the login values. Might as well click reset or something. There’s just no processing at all. Weird stuff man! ‍♂️